# Usage of "have"

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, past-perfect

I'm a little confused and I want to know which one of the sentences below is correct.

> After I’ve done that, everything has changed.
>
> After I had done that, everything changed.

Comment: you need to explain why you are confused and why you think they are either right ot wrong before we can answer you.

Answer (score 3):

The rules in this case are simple.

**After I have done this** has to be followed by something in the future, not a past or current action as in your first sentence. For example:

> After I have done that I will work in the garden.
>   After I have done that I will rest for a while.
>   After you have done that you should clean the car.
>   After we have done that we want to go swimming.

If you want to look back on things you did, you would typically use the **past** and **past perfect** tenses - as in your second sentence.

Here you are recounting the sequence of two or more things that you have already done. Frequently, you have the choice of using either the **simple past** or **past perfect** tense in the first half of the sentence. It's a matter of choice and context. Either:

> After I swam, I went home
>   or
>   After I had swum, I went home

So your second sentence is correct:

> After I had done that, everything changed.

Note anouk's comment that you are expected to explain exactly what puzzles you and what efforts you have made to resolve the problem yourself.